# Getting different TreeView SelectedNode index values in Vb.Net and VB6

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6, treeview

I have the code written in `VB6` is as follows:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_Click()

        mLastSelectedTab = TreeView1.SelectedItem.Index        
        TreeView1.SelectedItem.Bold = True
        mNodeItem.DoSelection "Items", TreeView1.SelectedItem.Index 
        TreeView1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

And code that I've written in `VB.NET` is something like this:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

       mLastSelectedTab = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Index 
       TreeView1.SelectedNode.NodeFont = New Font(TreeView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
       mNodeItem.DoSelection("Items", TreeView1.SelectedNode.Index) 
       TreeView1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

But the problem that I'm facing is when clicking on `TreeViewNode` I get a different result for `TreeView1.SelectedItem.Index` . In `VB6` it gets a value in same order as entered in list but in `VB.NET` it gets a value in order item is displayed in list.

Comment: .Net Node items are not a complete list of nodes of the TreeView, only the parent nodes.  To find ChildNodes, you would have to use the Find function or find the parent Node.  TreeView1.Enabled = True makes no sense since it was obviously already enabled.  What is "DoSelection"?

Comment: `_Click` handles `.AfterSelect` seems odd. And you have a discrepancy concerned with selection? Why not handle in click? Also the VB6 and .Net controls are not identical.

Comment: @LarsTech DoSelection method gets index value  and display outputs according to it.

Comment: @djv VB6 code gets a correct index values and display correct output according to that. But VB.NET code get wrong index values.

Comment: VB.Net gets *different* values. Clearly state your problem. I think you are trying to get *a value in same order as entered in list* in vb.net, is that correct?

Comment: @djv yes you are absolutely correct. But the value I’m getting is in order that it displays on TreeNode list.

Comment: And the same line code in VB6 gives me correct value(In a same order as entered)

Comment: Like I said, the .Net TreeView is not a list of all the nodes.  Each node has it's own list of child nodes.

Comment: @LarsTech So what is the possible solution of this problem?